# Не могу создать Flexbox-элемент

Tags: css, flexbox

Здравствуйте! Пытаюсь научиться делать сайты на практике, разбираясь по ходу, но сталкиваюсь с жестокой реальностью и всё валится с рук.
В общем примерно так всё должно выглядеть:

[image]

Так выглядит часть, которую я пытаюсь воссоздать с помощью flexbox'ов.
Как бы я не пытался его сделать, элементы никак не хотят встать туда, куда я хочу. Хочу сделать так, чтобы центральный элемент находился по середине, а левый и правый равнялись от него и при этом, если продолжить список, остальные элементы должны спускать ровно.

```css
.fx1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="fx1">
  <div>Первый Автор</div>
  <div>Второй Автор</div>
  <div>Третий Автор</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Если вы хотите, чтобы центральный элемент "находился посередине", то первый же вопрос возникает - это "известна ли (фиксирована) ширина среднего контейнера.

Comment: @AK фиксирована, конечно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

если вы хотите, чтобы ваши дочерние блоки выстроились равномерно по ширине родительского блока, используйте св-ва

```
justify-content:space-between;
justify-content:space-around;
```

[подробная информация по flexbox тут](https://html5book.ru/css3-flexbox/)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
b {
  display: block;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div><b>М. Җәлил</b>Кызыл<br>Ромашка</div>
  <div><b>М. Җәлил</b>Мокамай</div>
  <div><b>М. Җәлил</b>21<br>Апрель</div>
</div>
```

Comment: И судя по уточнению автора вопроса - ему не нужно равномерно по ширине, ему нужно, чтобы средний стал по центру. Для этого нужно уточнить, фиксирована ли ширина среднего блока. Так что пока ответ вряд ли стоит засчитывать.

Comment: так если у него всего 3 блока,то средний встанет по центру при обоих варинтах исполбзования justify-content

Comment: @SergeyKanyukov я всё скопировал, как у Вас, но всё равно у меня по центру столбом стоят и только. Не знаю, почему не работает.

Comment: @РасимХусаенов не совсем понял,что у вас не получается.Точнее, какого результата вы хотите добиться

Comment: @SergeyKanyukov сегодня снёс всё, скопировал Ваш код и всё заработало. К сожалению, оказалось, что это не совсем то. Мне нужно что-то вроде этого, (https://pp.userapi.com/c841637/v841637578/720cc/U_2g_JEmHJg.jpg) чтобы если сделать список, всё шло столбиком.

Comment: @РасимХусаенов задайте дополнительно родителю свойство flex-wrap: wrap; а детям св-во flex-basis: 30%;

Comment: @SergeyKanyukov не помогло. Мне кажется, что я ошибся, думая, что крайние элементы должны отталкиваться от среднего. Возможно, стоило зафиксировать левый и уже остальные отталкивать.

Comment: @РасимХусаенов flexbox не предполагают "отталкивание" элементов друг от друга. Если вы хотите так,как вы написали,тогда вам надо задать элементам float:left или display:inline-block и регулировать расстояние между ними отступами. Либо удалите у родителя св-во justify-content и так же регулируйте расстояние отступами.

Answer (score -1):

Flex задается родителскому элементу чтобы преобразовать дочерные.

```css
.main-wrap {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
.block-1 {
  background-color:lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-wrap">
  <div class="block-1">Bulbasaur</div>
  <div class="block-1">Pikachu</div>
  <div class="block-1">Chermander</div>
  <div class="block-1">Onix</div>
</div>
```